# Erklärung Nomen und Adjektive

Tags: nominalization

Wenn werden Adjektive als Nomen verwendent? Was sind die Klassen, in denen die Adjektive großgeschrieben werden? Zum Beispiel:

> Es wurde Süßes und Salziges serviert. Das lässt auf Besseres hoffen.
>   das Gute im Menschen das Wichtigste im Leben aufs Schlimmste
>   vorbereitet sein (siehe aber auch unten) Das ist das einzig Richtige.
>   Das von uns allen Erhoffte geschah.  seine Sehnsucht nach dem ihm
>   Unbekannten und Ähnliches (u. Ä.) Im Allgemeinen hast du Recht. Sie
>   taten es zum Besten der Kinder. Daran hatte ich nicht im Entferntesten
>   gedacht. Sie haben im Großen und Ganzen recht. Sie haben im großen
>   Ganzen recht. Wir waren bis ins Kleinste vorbereitet. Das kommt im
>   Wesentlichen auf das Gleiche hinaus. Ich lege auf Folgendes/das
>   Folgende großen Wert: Wir sind mit unten Stehendem (oder:
>   Untenstehendem) nicht einverstanden. Wir sind dem unten Stehenden
>   (oder: dem Untenstehenden) nicht einverstanden.
>
> Lass dich nicht mit Unbekannten ein! Die Reaktion des so
>   Angesprochenen war heftig. die Lebenden und die Toten Die Rat
>   Suchenden (oder: Ratsuchenden) kamen von überall her. Es soll ein
>   Programm für die Jungen und für die jung Gebliebenen (oder:
>   Junggebliebenen) werden. die Reformierten und die Römisch-Katholischen
>
> Nach Wörtern wie alles, allerlei, etwas, genug, nichts, viel, wenig,
>   jemand, niemand Ich wünsche dir alles Gute. Er erzählte allerlei
>   Wissenswertes. Oft greift man zu etwas Süßem als Seelentröster. Jetzt
>   hast du aber genug für keinen Menschen Verständliches von dir gegeben.
>   Die Diebe haben nichts wirklich Wertvolles gefunden. Wir haben wieder
>   viel/wenig Neues gehört. Er ist jemand sehr Besonderes. Hier wohnt
>   niemand Besonderes.
>
> In festen Wendungen wie zum Beispiel: beim Alten bleiben, es beim
>   Alten lassen im Argen liegen etwas zum Besten geben im Dunkeln tappen
>   etwas sein Eigen nennen jenseits von Gut und Böse sich über etwas im
>   Klaren sein auf dem Laufenden sein/halten auf dem Trockenen sitzen im
>   Ungewissen lassen

These are some rules but I dont know whenever I put *-es* or *-e* at the end of the word.

Comment: Answering for all these examples might be way too broad. The grammar rules that determine when and what adjectives and other word classes can be re-formed as a substantive, what the capitalisation is and whether you see a compound form as one or several words fill pages. Please split your question into smaller chunks. As it is now, it cannot be comprehensivly answered.

Comment: @tofro It is not really so broad as can be seen from this [nice summary at canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/A-To-N/A-To-N-Intro.html?MenuId=WordFormation1112) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Adjectives are used as nouns in sentences you call them nominalizations. You always write them capitalized. You can recognize them by a determiner, e.g.:

- a article: *das Gute*, *das Wichtigste*
- a pronoun: *alles Gute*, *etwas Süßes*
- a preposition: *aufs (auf das) Schlimmste*, *im Großen und Ganzen*

When you are not sure how to decline these words, see this [page](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/das-substantiv-nomen/deklination-nominalisierte-adjektive/).
Nominalized adjectives without a determiner end always with *-es*.

Comment: I want to know all cases where I allowed to enter the adjektivs as name

Comment: You may do this anytime you want. Some of the resulting nouns may sound clunky, but this doesn't prevent German speakers from using them.